# Треугольник без заливки

Tags: css

Подскажите, как создать треугольник с помощью css без бэкграунда?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берем квадратный блок, задаем левую и верхнюю границу, а затем поворачиваем на 45 градусов.

```css
.arrow {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как пример:

Пихаем один `div` в другой. Во внешнем назначаем `border` с одной стороны, у внутреннего - с двух других, при этом внутренний поворачиваем на 45 градусов и размещаем относительно первого.

```css
#wrapper {
  background: url(http://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/2017/03/19/2245758/tn/01-beautiful-white-cat-imagescar-wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat;
  
  height: 400px;
}
.container {
    width: 235px;
    height: 215px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 2px solid #e74c3c;
}

.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-left: 2px solid #e74c3c;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e74c3c;
    right: -75px;
    top: 32px;
}

.demo {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;    
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    width: 400px;
    height: 220px;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а получится этому треугольнику задать не  однородный фон ?

Comment: Неоднородный - это какой?

Comment: ну к примеру обычное изображение- ну море скажем !

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ну если для `container` поставить `overflow: hidden;` - то да.

Comment: я так делал - ерунда .. только на svg это реально

Comment: @МаксимЛенский покажи что ты имеешь в виду. может я не понимаю о чем ты говоришь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60004/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score -1):

может создать блок, в нем квадрат на 45 градусов повернутый, и сдвинуть вверх на 50% с overflow: hidden. Тогда получится у вас квадрат, которому можно поставить границу в 1px и без фона... как то так думаю, но не факт